# ¿Cómo abortar una función al clickear un botón?

Tags: php, javascript, funciones, redirección

Estoy arrojando una alerta al usuario cuando éste intente filtrar ciertos datos por url, al cargar la página, se mostrará dicha alerta, pero con un determinado tiempo para que el usuario decida rápidamente intentar de nuevo, o de lo contrario, será redireccionado a la home en segundos.
La cuestión es, que si éste le da clic en "**Intentar de nuevo**", se cancele la función que lo redirecciona, (la setTimeout), y se quede en la página en que está:

```
            <script>
            var stemen = true; 
        //Aquí empieza la alerta:
            $.confirm({
                            title: '¡Oops!',
                            content: '<center>Parece que tu correo no coincide con el que se registró. <br><br> <small><i>Ésta ventana se cerrará automáticamente.</i></small></center>',
                            type: 'red',
                            typeAnimated: true,
                            icon: 'fa fa-warning',
                            buttons: {
                                tryAgain: {
                                    text: 'Intentar de nuevo',
                                    btnClass: 'btn-red',
                                    action: function(){
                                        $('#modalRegistro').modal('show'); 
                                        stemen = false; //Aquí intento abortar la función
                                    }
                                },
                                close: function (){
                                    window.location.href = '".$url."';
                                }
                            }
                        }); //Aquí termina la alerta

        //Y aquí estoy tratando de hacer la función
    veam(stemen); 
    function veam(stemen){ 

    if(typeof stemen != 'undefined' && stemen === true){
    setTimeout( window.location.href = '".$url."', 57000)
    }else{return false;} console.log(stemen); 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método **setTimeout()** devuelve el identificador del temporizador que hemos creado, entonces debes guardarla en una variable así:

```
let timerIrAlHome = setTimeout(function() {
  // redireccionarl al home
}, 4000);
```

Luego en el action del botón **tryAgain** pones:

`clearTimeout(timerIrAlHome);`

Esto lo que hace es borrar el temporizador que creamos.

Acerca de:

- [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)
- [clearTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout)

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: Gracias Oscar, si te fijas bien, yo no estoy usando ningun **setInterval()** , de hecho, estoy usando el **setTimeout()**

Comment: Estaba seguro de haber visto el setInterval, vale, espera edito la respuesta, pero en sí, lo que debes hacer es guardar el identificador del temporizador en una variable y luego borrarlo.

Comment: Dale Oscar, muchas gracias, lo intentaré aver qué tal.

Comment: Vale, ya edité la respuesta. Quedo atento.

Comment: Oscar, una última preguntica, cómo puedo ahora ejecutar esa función de esa variable?, es decir, ya pegué el código de la variable con la función, antes de la alerta, y en el el botón **tryAgain** de mi alerta, puse el `clear​Timeout(timerIrAlHome);` , pero resulta que me arroja un error en la consola el cual dice: **SyntaxError: illegal character**, en la misma línea donde puse el `clear​Timeout(timerIrAlHome);`

Comment: Bueno pues este error es cuando se usan caracteres que no se permiten en javascript, revisa de pronto te quedó una cadena sin cerrar o algo así...

[Acerca del error](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/caracter_ilegal)

Comment: `var stemen = setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = '".$url."'; }, 4000);           $.confirm({
content: 'Ésta ventana se cerrará sola',
buttons: {
tryAgain: {
text: 'Intentar de nuevo',
action: function(){ $('#modalRegistro').modal('show'); 
                             clear​Timeout(stemen); }
},
close: function (){window.location.href = '".$url."';}} 
});`
**Está tal cual, y no me funciona, por eso te pregunté que de qué manera podía ejecutar la función que está en la variable donde está el setTimeout**

Comment: No sé amigo, parece que tienes un caracter extraño en el clearTimeout()... aquí tengo la prueba que funciona. [Ver código](https://jsfiddle.net/lechediaz/ryjc9fe5/11/)

Comment: Cesar Romero encontró el carácter especial que mencionaba el OP, razón por la que le fallaba el código.